# Accessing Solr 8 from C#

Tags: solr, solrnet

Sigh... I may have just made a mistake upgrading our solr server to the latest version but not sure. The c# calls are giving me errors now. I assume we're using "SolrNet" only because I'm not aware of another .net implementation (I didn't do the implementation is why I'm not sure yet), but I am seeing now that on the NuGet page it says it's only supports Solr up to version 7.x.

Is there an api that supports Solr 8 that will work in .net or will I have to downgrade to version 7?

Comment: The API should be the same - are you able to access the admin page of your Solr instance? (i.e. are you sure you haven't broken Solr?)

Comment: Yep, we are using solr8 with SolrNet latest version and works like a charm. Maybe your solr port has changed?